# show picture from jTable in jsp

Tags: hibernate, jsp, servlets, jquery-jtable

I use jTable  to display information in the database
That's the problem
How can I display the images in the table
I need a sample to implement what I'm thinking of
I want to use the jsp page

Comment: Show us your code and effort done from your side. Let us know where you stuck exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but this question does seem to be of interest. All you need is a display function for your image column. Something like

```
image: {
    title: 'Image',
    list: true,
    edit: false,
    create: false,
    display: function (data) {
        return $('<img />')
            .attr('src',data.record.image)
            .addClass("my-image-styling-class"); 
    }
},
```

This assumes the server is sending the full url of the image.

I personally avoiding send the real url of an image file, I'd rather go through an image server app, so I'd have the server send a processed url or replace the src line with something like

```
.attr('src','myImageServer.php?id='+ data.record.image)
```